# Чем отличается понятие "viewport" на мониторе от понятий "layout viewport" и "visual viewport" на смартфоне?

Tags: css, css3

Привет.

Чем отличается понятие "viewport" на мониторе от понятий "layout viewport" и "visual viewport" на смартфоне? В каких пикселях они измеряются (в пикселях железа или пикселях CSS)? Чем отличается зумминг на смартфоне от зумминга на мониторе?

Comment: Рекомендую Илью Григорика, он очень хорошо про viewport-ы пишет.

Comment: не встречал его статей про вьюпорты. можете ссылку кинуть?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html

Comment: это я читал в русском переводе. не понял все равно